# listFiles() returns null on removable storage

Tags: android, kotlin, usb-otg

I want to read from an OTG USB but listFiles() returns nothing.
I'm able to get the path for the removable storage but couldn't access the files

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity

```
private fun getReadPermission() {
    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_READ_STORAGE)
}

private fun read() {
    fileList = ArrayList()
    val volumes = this.getExternalFilesDirs(null)
    val path = volumes[1]
    val dir = File("$path/")
    readUSB(dir)
}

private fun readUSB(dir: File) {

    val files = dir.listFiles()

    files?.forEach {
        if (it.isDirectory) {
            readUSB(it)
        } else {
            fileList.add("${it.absolutePath}")

        }

    }

    binding.files.text = fileList.toString()

}
```

Comment: `getExternalFilesDirs()` does not return the root of storage volumes. It returns a directory that is unique to your app (per volume). So, `path` will not point to the root of your removable storage device, if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is my first time dealing with such a problem any suggestions for a resource to begin with?

Comment: "any suggestions for a resource to begin with?" -- for what, specifically?

Comment: I do not believe that listFiles returns null. What it does instead is returning an empty list. Please examine and report.

Comment: Which Android version on used device? And you forgot to tell that path.

Comment: `val path = volumes[1]` Why [1]? Please explain. The list is empty as the directory does not contain files.